# Bad quality ground LiDAR cloud points

Tags: lidar, noise

[image]

I got this point cloud using slam100 laser scanner, but seems to have an bad quality,  someone said its all noisy, how could I fix that?

Comment: Sensor noise is very common in LiDAR, fixing that can be a tedious time consuming task. First, what level of classification do you desire? There is automated classifcation that can clean up most of the noise, after that there is manual editing. You will need GIS software to achieve automated classification, what software do you have available to work with? If you do not currently have GIS software consider QGIS (free and open source) with LASTools (most tools will work without a license but the results are warped or marked), however in QGIS it is not (yet) possible to manually edit LAS.